# What does "through the prism of my senses" mean?

Tags: literature

Taken from V. Nabokov's Lolita

"through the prism of my senses they were as different as mist and mast"

Hmmm?

Comment: Hmmm. What part of the meaning are you having trouble with? Please expand your question to make it easier for us to write a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

A prism separates light into monochromatic colors, the hues of the rainbow.  This kind of separation is used in colorimetry in order to describe reflective colors in terms of more than the three perceived primary color sensitivies: this is necessary for accounting for different surface's appearance under different lighting conditions: for example, two batches of car paint might match perfectly under sunlight but completely different under metal vapor street lamps.

So a "prism of my senses" supposedly separates a composite impression into separate components, indicating a difference in a lot of details in contrast to more similarity of the overall impression.